# Is this question about DJ equipment a good fit for Music.SE?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'm asking about this question: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14272/what-are-the-most-important-pieces-of-equipment-for-a-beginning-dj-to-have

It asks for a list of equipment for a beginning DJ. Does the fact that it asks for a list put it in the Bad Subjective or Shopping Cart categories of questions, or is it specific enough to be a good question?

Comment: The edits you've made to the question bring it a long way. Kudos!

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a good question. The list it asks for seems to me to be an example of a Good Subjective question:

- There are only a few good answers. There are pieces of equipment DJs need, and there's equipment that they don't need.
- Although some people might disagree on specific answers, I would expect that for this kind of question, there are only a few viewpoints that experts often hold, so the most common views will float to the top.

Comment: you make a good point, and I agree with you. Take a look [here](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/623/why-are-questions-about-recommendations-of-pieces-to-play-off-topic). It is pretty much the same question that I had and Dr Mayhem (moderator) answered me

Answer (score 2):

The question will stay closed because it is not fit for the site. We don't recommend equipment or answer opinionated questions.

Let's put it another way: If a guitarist asked a question "What effects pedals should I get?" how are we suppose to answer that? We don't know what songs he plays, we don't know his budget, and we don't know what he already has so answering the question would be almost be useless. Not to mention it will likely not be useful for anyone else.

The same issues carry over for a DJ. We can try to make a similar wiki to the [guitar effects](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/glossary-of-guitar-effects), but that too feels like the answers will not be too useful for for anyone else because the topic itself is very opinionated.

Comment: But, for a similar question for a performing guitarist, I'd answer, "A tuner pedal, a noise gate, and good in-ear monitors," as opposed to effects (which are, as you say, subjective).

Comment: acheong87 - I would disagree with you, though, as I would not get a tuner pedal, I may get a noise gate, but it is not that useful for me, and while I might want in ear monitors, they are way down the list of priorities. See - very subjective.

Comment: @DrMayhem - Interesting. I guess I thought most would agree on at least a tuner and a noise gate. (But wouldn't you say most beginning guitarists should have a tuner on-stage, on a rack if not a pedal (but most beginners have pedals...) Anyway, I don't mean to be argumentative. I think my point was more that some subjective questions may have near-objective answers when enough consensus exists. For example, as an answer to one of Dom's own questions, http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/a/606/6041. (Of course, that question is much more useful and interesting than mine.)

Comment: I was kind of deliberately taking the Devil's advocate position - as things are just too subjective. I do have a tuner but after soundcheck I really don't need it. I don't use a noise gate at all these days, and didn't when I was a new guitarist (although there was a phase where I loved them!)...